# How to use template reference variable in angular 11

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am trying to use the template reference variable in my angular app in my vscode it gives me an error like **Property 'button' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor**.

how can I use it? I try something like this:-

```
 @ViewChild('button', { static: true }) button: ElementRef;
```

package.json

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~11.0.6",
    "@angular/common": "~11.0.6",
    "@angular/compiler": "~11.0.6",
    "@angular/core": "~11.0.6",
    "@angular/forms": "~11.0.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~11.0.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~11.0.6",
    "@angular/router": "~11.0.6",
    "jspdf": "^2.2.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1100.6",
    "@angular/cli": "~11.0.6",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~11.0.6",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~4.0.2"
```

Comment: See here: https://fluin.io/blog/property-has-no-initializer-and-is-not-definitely-assigned

Comment: but when I try to use the button in my function it gives me an error like the button is undefined.

Comment: try change the name of the variable `button` for something like `buttonControl`. BTW, As you write `{static:true}` this mean that the button must be always visible -not put under a `*ngIf`-